# Resilience4j How to route to fallback method then return back to original method after specific amount of time

Tags: spring-boot, circuit-breaker, fault-tolerance, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I am working with resilience4j and spring boot,

I need to accomplish the below scenario,

- When I have a failure in the **originalMethod**
- After 5 attempts route to the **fallback** method
- After a specific time like 5 minutes return back to the **originalMethod**

I tried with **retry** as below but does not fit the problem ,

```
     @Retry(name = "retryService", fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    public String originalMethod(String data) throws InterruptedException {
        //..... call external service 
    }

public String fallback(String data, Throwable t) {
        logger.error("Inside retryfallback, cause – {}", t.toString());
        return "Inside retryfallback method. Some error occurred ";
    }
```

**Added properties**

```
resilience4j.retry:
  instances:
    retryService:
      maxRetryAttempts: 5
      waitDuration: 50000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a circuit breaker for sometime when a failure limit reached to achieve the behavior you want.

By adding @CircuitBreaker(...) annotation and specifying the failureRateThreshold, waitDurationInOpenState and the other needed config properties for that instance.